# 'vue-property-decorator' cannot compatible with Jest when testing in Vue project

Tags: typescript, vue.js, jestjs, babeljs, vue-property-decorator

When I only use Jest with Vue project, I can't import subcomponent in component,

if I do according to tips, also I cannot define private variable

the reproduce project :[jest-decorator-issue](https://github.com/magicalcosmos/jest-decorator-issue)

also can be find here: [issue and image](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-property-decorator/issues/413)

I don't know why, can anyone give me any suggestions?